# Stacked bar chart with bokeh and pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, bokeh

I am trying to make a stacked bar chart in bokeh using a pandas dataframe, and I want to change which column is used to designate the separate bars, and which column is used to designate the stacked units within a bar.

My data looks like this

```
                Count
  Continent  Am | As | E
  Category
  A           5    0   0
  B           2    0   0
  C           0    0   9
  D           0    6   0
  E           0    0   3
```

Bokeh is automatically making "Category" the bars and "Continent" the stacked units. I'd like to do the inverse.

The code I'm using is simply

```
p = Bar(data, stacked=True)
show(p)
```

Thanks for any help!

J

Comment: Have you tried transposing the DataFrame?